# Pass Value between functions - object reference was not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, struct

I'm trying to make a program to college in c#. I'm supposed to do a stuct and save there the weight, height, name, code and BMI for each athlete. I don't know how many athletes the person will add to the program but the arrays must increase dynamically, I can't waste unneeded memory.

I came up with this: (The Button 1 Shows the athletes and the button 2 adds them.)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
int numeroDeAtletas = 1;
Atleta[] atletas;

public struct Atleta
{
    public string nomes;
    public int codigos;
    public double altura;
    public double peso;
    public double IMC;
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (numeroDeAtletas-1); i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nome : " + atletas[i].nomes + Environment.NewLine + "Código: " + atletas[i].codigos + Environment.NewLine + "Peso: " + atletas[i].peso + Environment.NewLine + "Altura: " + atletas[i].altura + Environment.NewLine + "Indíce de massa corporal: " + atletas[i].IMC, "Atleta " + (i+1), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Atleta[] atletas = new Atleta[numeroDeAtletas];
    atletas[numeroDeAtletas - 1].nomes = txtName.Text;
    atletas[numeroDeAtletas - 1].codigos = Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text);
    atletas[numeroDeAtletas - 1].peso = Convert.ToDouble(txtWeight.Text);
    atletas[numeroDeAtletas - 1].altura = Convert.ToDouble(txtHeight.Text);
        AtletasMng atletasmng = new AtletasMng (Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text),txtName.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtWeight.Text), Convert.ToDouble(txtHeight.Text));
        atletas[numeroDeAtletas - 1].IMC = atletasmng.calcularIMC();
        MessageBox.Show("Atleta número " + (numeroDeAtletas) + " adicionado com sucesso!");

        numeroDeAtletas++;

        if (numeroDeAtletas >= 2)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

}

But when I click the button 1 it says "object reference was not set to an instance of an object", I think it's because the line:

```
 Atleta[] atletas = new Atleta[numeroDeAtletas];
```

is declaring a local variable that is not being passed onto the button1_Click() function. How can I pass the values between this funcions, then?

Comment: Use ``List<T>`` if you dont know the no of items that will be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**List**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this scenario.

Declare a `List` of type `Atleta` in your class and  then use it, as you said that number of items are dynamic not fixed:

Add a field in your class of type `List<Atleta>`:

```
List<Atleta> atletas = new List<Atleta>();
```

On Button click add to list this way:

```
 Atleta atleta = new Atleta();
 atleta.nomes = txtName.Text;
 atleta.codigos = Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text);
 atleta .peso = Convert.ToDouble(txtWeight.Text);
 atleta.altura = Convert.ToDouble(txtHeight.Text);
 ...................
 ...................
 ...................
 atletas.Add(Atleta);
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time that you press button 2 you are deleting existing atletas with

```
Atleta[] atletas = new Atleta[numeroDeAtletas];
```

but if `numeroDeAtletas` (for example) is 3 you valorize only the last record of the array, the others are empty!

for your purpose I suggest you to use [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

replace `Atleta[] atletas;` with `List<Atleta> atletas= new List<Atleta>();`

and every time that you click Button2 you can do

```
atletas.Add(new Atleta{option1="test", option2="test"});
```